# Internet access on debian using external gateway

Tags: networking, debian

I've checked online for a solution to this but not having any joy, i'm sure it's pretty simple to fix as well. I did find https://serverfault.com/questions/ask?title=debian%20private%20gateway which I thought was similar but still couldn't fix my issue.
I'm using a Debian machine (10.0.0.1) and trying to connect to the internet via a gateway which isn't part of the same network (192.168.100.254). I don't have access to the gateway but the Debian machine is (and must stay) connected to the external network via a switch.

```
My Debian /etc/networking/interfaces is
auto eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.100.254
broadcast 10.0.0.255


route -n
Destination   Gateway   Genmask       Flags     Metric    Ref   Use   Iface
10.0.0.0     0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0  U          0         0    0    eth0
```

I've tried ip route add 10.0.0.1 via 192.168.100.254 but that didn't solve the issue. Also tried with/without having the gateway in /interfaces but still didn't fix it. If I change the IP address to one that's within the network, it works fine and I can ping/nslookup fine.

Does anyone know where i'm going wrong or can point me in the right  direction please?

Comment: Where does the link lead to, again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, your default gateway **must** be on the same subnet. You'll need to talk with whomever runs this network to get things fixed up.

Communication between any two subnets requires the assistance of a layer 3 router, so in your case, there needs to be a router with interfaces on both of those subnets for you to have a working internet connection.

Comment: In that case, would it be possible to use another router, connected to the switch which is connected to the Debian machine as the middle man? Or would this again, not work?

Comment: Honestly, you need to read up on IP routing and learn about this.

Comment: I agree, i've had a look up on it and have solved my own question by using a router/switch and connecting it that way. My apologies for wasting your time and thanks for the swift response.